# Filter Files that the current user has permissions to view

Tags: silverstripe

I want to query the files against a search term, and only show the files the current user has permissions to view.

```php
    $files_basic = File::get()->filterAny([
      'Title:PartialMatch' => $s,
      'FileFilename:PartialMatch' => $s,
      'Description:PartialMatch' => $s,
      'DisplayName:PartialMatch' => $s
    ]);
```

How can I add that filter to my query above?

I know I can restrict the file in the template:

```ss
 <% if $canView %>
```

However that is insufficient as I don't want to fetch not-allowed records and include them at all in the displayed list, pagination counts etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Filter file permissions as part of the query (the really hard way):**

What you want is theoretically possible but in almost all cases not practical.

The information what user can view what file is not a simple direct database relation that you can query. If you want to do it at query time, you have to:

- filter differently based on CanViewType (inherited, everyone, any user, user in specific group)
- if a file's CanViewType is group, you have to get all groups for that user and check for a match of that group
- if it's inherited, check if the file is in a folder, and if so, validate the permissions based on the folder

additionally, you should make sure that there is no additional php based permission checking done by any extension that expends `canView` of file/folder

---

**Filter in php with `canView` right after the query (the more practical way):**

Unless you really have a query that needs to fetch thousands of files, the more practical solution is to fetch all files and then loop/filter them in php. In most cases, this is "fast enough" and much easier to do.

Using `canView` in php instead of the template means you can still do things like pagination and correct row counts.

The Silverstripe ORM provides `->filterByCallback()` for ease of use instead of looping. But keep in mind that performance wise this is the same as a foreach (because internally it fetches the whole list and runs a foreach)

```php
 $member = \SilverStripe\Security\Security::getCurrentUser();
 $files_basic = File::get()->filterAny([
      'Title:PartialMatch' => $s,
      'FileFilename:PartialMatch' => $s,
      'Description:PartialMatch' => $s,
      'DisplayName:PartialMatch' => $s
])->filterByCallback(function($file) use ($member) {
      // return false will remove the item from the list
      return $file->canView($member);
});
```

Comment: great, thanks.  Ill avoid TheReallyHardWay as suggested.